# How do I upload images to a specific folder (Component Backend)

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, administrator

I would like to know how I upload files to a specific folder through Joomla Administrator Panel (My Component Backend).

I know how to do it in the site part following along with this tutorial:

> https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/J3.2:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_an_Image#site.2Fcontrollers.2Fhelloworld.php

However I don't know how to do the same thing in the backend part.

I have this in my `controller` file to edit and add a new image:

```
protected function allowAdd($data = array())
    {
        return parent::allowAdd($data);
    }


  protected function allowEdit($data = array(), $key = 'id')
    {
        $id = isset( $data[ $key ] ) ? $data[ $key ] : 0;
        if( !empty( $id ) )
        {
            return JFactory::getUser()->authorise( "core.edit", "com_gallery.image." . $id );
        }
    }
```

I could use my own code inside these functions but I think I won't be able to check if the user has permissions to execute these actions. I'm not sure what `JFactory::getUser()->authorise()` is for but I think it authorises the user to perform actions when they have permission to do so.

**So my question is:**

Is there any way to use my own upload code and check whether the user has permissions to execute that action or not?

Comment: Not a solution but my advice is not to generate single-use variables.   Remove the `$id` declaration line and just use `if (!empty($data[$key])) { ..."com_gallery.image." . $data[$key]); }`

Comment: The question isn't very clear. What are you doing in frontend that doesn't work in backend? Why do you need different checks for frontend and backend?

Comment: Actually I'm developing a custom component that allow users to upload images. I would like to upload these images to a cloud storage instead of storing them in default Joomla folder which is `media/images` (I believe). I can do it easily in frontend but I would like to be able to manage these images from my backend but I don't have as much control as I do in the frontend seeing as in the backend I have that "premade" function to update the images, doing all the job for me. So what would be the best approach to do it? Just put my own code inside the function `allowEdit` and `allowAdd` ?

Comment: That's exactly my problem by the way. I don't want different checks haha. I want to be able to upload images to the same place from both frontend and backend. But in the backend I have that `allowEdit` and `allowAdd` function that saves the image to the default local Joomla folder. It follows the same sctruture as this tutorial https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Introduction

Comment: Well, I have come to a conclusion that Joomla - despite being a great platform - does not offer the level of scalability and flexibility that I need. But it was a pleasure meeting you all. I will definitely use Joomla for future projects instead of others CMS

Comment: `allowAdd`/`allowEdit` methods shouldn't be uploading anything.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for your clarification. Anyway I think a pure PHP Framework will work out better for me. That was my first question here by the way; I wanted to use The Joomla! Framework (just the framewok) but it didn't work so I ended up using the CMS. But thank you for baring with me all this time and I apologise for anything that I may have done.